# Laravel Array Validation - Continue with passed items

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5.5

I would like to apply validation rules a request containing an array but handle each exception separately, and continue with the elements that passed the validation.

Lets say I have

```
{ students: [ {name: 'foo'}, {name: 'barbaz' ] }
```

and my validator looks

like this:

```
$validatedStudents = request()->validate([
     'students.*.name' => 'required|string|max:3'
 ]);
```

I still want to continue with student 'foo' and handle student 'barbaz' separately. Laravel will throw an exception for the entire request and don't continue with any students.

One solution to this would be to loop through students and validate each student, but this is not possible since

```
foreach (request()->all() as $student) { ... }
```

will give $student as array and not request. Is it possible to run validate on array/collection like a request?

Thanks

Comment: 1. Validate manually 2. Filter your request 3.Save/Update your request 4. throw exception if any. Try once

Comment: How would you validate manually?

Comment: Check this : https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#manually-creating-validators

Comment: But why you need this ? As you already getting back with you previous data you can update and pass with validated data or remove the part which have problem?

Comment: I can validate each item with laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#manually-creating-validators and handle error separately just how I wanted it. Thank you.